# Insert or delete into non-overlapping continuous interval collection

Tags: java, algorithm, performance, intervals

Given a collection of sorted non-overlapping continuous intervals, how to add new interval or delete existing interval from it. Please suggest me a good data structure to store these intervals which can make these changes possible.

Example:

```
Given collection: [1,4), [4,9), [9,12)

Insert: [5,8)
Result: [1,4), [4,5), [5, 8), [8, 9), [9, 12)

Delete: [4, 5)
Result: [1,5),  [5, 8), [8, 9), [9, 12)
```

In case of delete it should add to the previous first if possible otherwise next one(s).

Comment: You can use a `TreeSet` and define a comparator to control the sorting.

Comment: Thank you, I am already using TreeSet, but I have an issue with insert, delete and edits. My question was, how to do them efficiently?

Answer (score 1):

I'd simply not bother with the discrete intervals. 
Since definintion requires "sorted non-overlapping continuous intervals", I'd only store the boundaries of the intervals ("`intervalBoundaries`") and from that list, I'd create the interval ranges on demand ("`getRanges()`").

Here my example (maybe the "`deleteRange()`"-method should be revised to cover edge cases):

```
/*
 */
package de.test.stackoverflow;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;

public class Intervals {

    public static final class Range {

        final int from;
        final int to;

        public Range(int from, int to) {
            this.from = from;
            this.to = to;
        }

        public int getFrom() {
            return from;
        }

        public int getTo() {
            return to;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return String.format("[%d, %d)", from, to);
        }

    }

    final SortedSet<Integer> intervalBoundaries = new java.util.TreeSet<>();

    public List<Range> getRanges() {
        final List<Range> res = new java.util.ArrayList<>();
        if (intervalBoundaries.size() > 1) {
            final List<Integer> tmpBounds = new java.util.ArrayList<>(intervalBoundaries);
            for (int i = 0; i < tmpBounds.size() - 1; i++) {
                res.add(new Range(tmpBounds.get(i), tmpBounds.get(i + 1)));
            }
        }
        return res;
    }

    public void insertBoundary(Integer bound) {
        // duplicates in sets are automatically removed
        intervalBoundaries.add(bound);
    }

    public void insertRange(Integer from, Integer to) {
        intervalBoundaries.add(from);
        intervalBoundaries.add(to);

    }

    public void insertRange(Range x) {
        insertRange(x.getFrom(), x.getTo());
    }

    public void deleteRange(Range x) {
        final Collection<Integer> boundsToDelete = new java.util.LinkedHashSet<>();
        for (Integer intervalBoundary : intervalBoundaries) {
            if (intervalBoundary >= x.getFrom() && intervalBoundary < x.getTo()) {
                boundsToDelete.add(intervalBoundary);
            }
        }
        intervalBoundaries.removeAll(boundsToDelete);
        if (x.getTo() < intervalBoundaries.last()) {
            insertBoundary(x.getTo());
        }
        if (x.getFrom() > intervalBoundaries.last()) {
            insertBoundary(x.getFrom());
        }
    }    

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Intervals i = new Intervals();
        i.insertRange(new Range(1, 4));
        i.insertRange(new Range(4, 9));
        i.insertRange(new Range(9, 12));
        System.out.println("Given collection: " + StringUtils.join(i.getRanges(), ", "));
        final Range insertRange = new Range(5, 8);
        System.out.println("insert: " + insertRange);
        i.insertRange(insertRange);
        System.out.println("Result: " + StringUtils.join(i.getRanges(), ", "));
        final Range deleteRange = new Range(4, 5);
        System.out.println("delete: " + deleteRange);
        i.deleteRange(deleteRange);
        System.out.println("Result: " + StringUtils.join(i.getRanges(), ", "));
        final Range deleteRange2 = new Range(3, 9);
        System.out.println("delete: " + deleteRange2);
        i.deleteRange(deleteRange2);
        System.out.println("Result: " + StringUtils.join(i.getRanges(), ", "));
        final Range deleteRange3 = new Range(2, 15);
        System.out.println("delete: " + deleteRange3);
        i.deleteRange(deleteRange3);
        System.out.println("Result: " + StringUtils.join(i.getRanges(), ", "));

    }

}
```

Comment: You should describe how your code works (the main ideas behind it, and any trade-offs), instead of only dumping code. Some caveats in your solution would be that there is no easy way to query whether a point is part of an interval or not, and removing ranges will mess up your data-structure. For example, given `[1, 2), [2, 3), [3, 4)`, removing `[2, 3)` does not currently result in `[1, 2), [3, 4)`, but rather in `[1, 3), [3, 4)` (!!)

Comment: did some of it... BTW: [1, 2), [3, 4) is not part of the specification

Comment: one of the delete case giving wrong result. Deleting [3,9) should result in [1,3), [9,12). But I got your idea of inserting and deleting. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not quite sure whether your specification is correct then.
You deleted `[4,5)` from `[1,4), [4,5), [5, 8), [8, 9), [9, 12)` and the result remains "sorted non-overlapping continuous" `[1,5),  [5, 8), [8, 9), [9, 12)`. Maybe your question is unclear at this point, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, when you delete [4,5) the result should be [1,5), [5, 8), [8, 9), [9, 12). And it is sorted non-overlapping. This is what I expected.

Comment: Plus `[1,5), [5, 8), [8, 9), [9, 12)` is continuous. Why should deleting `[3,9)` result in `[1,3)[9,12)`, which is not continuous?
Could you provide more "input-delete-output" triplets, please?
Your specification does not state clearly about deletions.